# set specific dimension or minimum upload size

Tags: images

How can I require specific dimensions for an image for an upload form? For example, I want to set the image to be uploaded in 350x200px, or show a notice to the user if the image size is not correct.

Alternatively, can I set a minimum upload size?

Answer (score 0):

Add these code to your theme function file.

```
add_image_size('mythumb', 350, 200, array( 'left', 'top' ));
// third parameter is for cropped option, you can change that as your preference.
the_post_thumbnail( 'mythumb' );// image with the new dimensions.
```

Important: you need to regenerate thumbnails to make this work. You can use plugin for that. For complete study, check official guide:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: Hi, I'm using dokan plugin, will this work?

Comment: My answer is wrong for your requirement, Please follow the possible duplicate link to get the solution specific to your requirement.

Comment: Can I use a javascript inside the php? may I ask the script?

Comment: Yes you can. `<?php //your php code. ?><script> Your javaScript code. </script><?php //your php code ?>`